# JPA Exceptions: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have created `One to many` relationship between `User` and `Items` table. Below is both `sql` and `java` code. I am getting exception caused by:

> org.hibernate.MappingException`: Could not determine type for: com.model.Users, at table: items, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(users)]

Please help in mapping.

```sql
    CREATE TABLE users
    ( id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('userseq'::regclass),
      email character varying(64) NOT NULL,
      passwords character varying(64) NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )
  
    CREATE TABLE items
    ( id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('itemseq'::regclass),
      userid integer NOT NULL,
      itemname character varying(4096) NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT message_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
      CONSTRAINT userid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (userid)
      REFERENCES users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
     )
```

```java
       public class Users  {
        private Items items;
            
            @OneToMany(targetEntity=Items.class, mappedBy="users", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)  //sender is message(c)filed
            public List<Items> getItems() {
                return items;
            }
        }
        
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Users.class)
            @JoinColumn(name = "userid", nullable = false)            // sendid is database column
            public Users getUsers() {
                return users;
            }
```

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.model.Users, at table: items, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(users)]

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.model.Users, at table: items, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(users)]

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: users, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(items)]

Comment: Please add Item entity as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is Users class not supposed to have a list of items? Try the following,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Items> items;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class Items{

    @JoinColumn(name="userid")
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

}
```